Simplify the equation with eight probabilities
If two probabilities $P_1, P_2$ are considered, we can have

$(1-P_1)P_2+P_1(1-P_2)+(1-P_1)(1-P_2)$.

If three are considered, we have

$(1-P_1)P_2P_3+P_1(1-P_2)P_3+P_1P_2(1-P_3)+(1-P_1)(1-P_2)P_3+...+(1-P_1)(1-P_2)(1-P_3)$.

If we have $n$ probabilities, can we simplify this equation or problem? Thanks!!

This is not clear.  Are you looking for something that measures the probability that at least one event does not happen? If so,  that's the complement of "all the events happen". Keep in mind,  though,  they we don't know that these are independent

If you are just looking at formal expressions without clear probabilistic meaning,  then a couple examples should reveal the result,  which is then easy to prove.

Yes, I just want to get a general expression for this problem. Can you provide me with a few directions or answers? Thanks a lot!!

For what problem? You don't actually say what is that you are trying to do.

I believe your equation can be simplified into:
$$1 - \Pi_{i=1}^{n}{P_i}$$
